# php json_decode disordered array

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I´m sending a javascript object through ajax with this structruce

```
[
  {  name:'box', price:'20', id:'72', units : 2 },
  {  name:'box2', price:'30', id:'73', units : 2 },
  {  name:'box3', price:'40', id:'74', units : 2 }
]
```

Getting the data on the server this way

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);
$queryconst = '';
foreach($data as $key => $value){
    $format[$key] = $value;
    $format_keys = array_keys($format[$key]);
    $newArray = $this->slashesToArray($value);
    $queryconst = $queryconst.'(\''.implode("','", $newArray).'\'),';           
}
$queryconst = rtrim($queryconst, ",");
$query = "INSERT INTO format (".implode(",", $format_keys).") VALUES ".$queryconst;
```

If the data that i`m sending has a single object

```
[
  {  name:'box', price:'20', id:'72', units : 2 }
]
```

everything works fine

```
$query = INSERT INTO format (name,units,price,id) VALUES ('box','2','20','72')
```

the problem comes when the data has more than one object

```
[
  {  name:'box', price:'20', id:'72', units : 2 },
  {  name:'box2', price:'30', id:'73', units : 2 },
  {  name:'box3', price:'40', id:'74', units : 2 }
]
```

and the query

```
$query = INSERT INTO format (price,name,units,product_id) 
         VALUES ('box','2','20','74'),('30','box2','2','74'),('40','box3','2','74')
```

the order fo the first object is different from the rest and the query fails

Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've fixed it, just ordering the array at the begining of the loop

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);
$queryconst = '';
foreach($data as $key => $value){
    ksort($value);
    $format[$key] = $value;
    $format_keys = array_keys($format[$key]);
    $newArray = $this->slashesToArray($value);
    $queryconst = $queryconst.'(\''.implode("','", $newArray).'\'),';           
}
$queryconst = rtrim($queryconst, ",");
$query = "INSERT INTO format (".implode(",", $format_keys).") VALUES ".$queryconst;
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON objects are *unordered*. Nothing in the spec or any implementation is guaranteeing any particular order when iterating, encoding or decoding JSON objects. You have to use the object key names explicitly instead of implicitly relying on their order.

Something along these lines:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);

// this is your whitelisting against column injection
$allowedColumns = ['name', 'price', ...];
$columns = array_keys($data[0]);
if (array_diff($columns, $allowedColumns)) {
    throw new InvalidArgumentException;
}

$values = [];
foreach ($data as $row) {
    // this maps the values to the column names in the right order, including escaping
    $values[] = array_map(function ($column) use ($row) {
        return sprintf("'%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($row[$column]));
    }, $columns);
}

$query = sprintf(
    'INSERT INTO (%s) VALUES %s',
    join(', ', $columns),
    join(', ', array_map(function ($row) {
        return sprintf('(%s)', join(', ', $row));
    }, $values))
);
```

Note the use of `mysql_real_escape_string` for proper escaping. Note also that this is deprecated and your should use PDO or mysqli with placeholders and parameter binding instead.